# Powershell Where-Object comparison with variable

Tags: powershell, comparator

i am trying to gather a specific eventID from a specific User using Get-Winevent, like this :

```
$UserID=Get-ADUser -Identity Administrator | Select-Object -Property "SID"

Get-WinEvent Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational |
Where-Object {$_.ID -match "1102" -and $_.UserId -match $UserID} | Format-List -Property *
```

The problem: When i compare with $UserID, i get no results. If i compare with the actual SID, i get the result  i want. I have tried every comparator i could find or think of, so i think i am missing something basic here but i don't know what and i'd like to learn.
Many thanks in Advance for any help !

Comment: I think the piece you're missing might be: `$UserSID = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new("$Domain\$UserID").Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, i had to specify which Property i needed from $USERID by using $USERID.SID instead.

Comment: Nice find.  That's correct.  When you use `Select -Property SID` it still return an object but with only that property so to access the value you still need to use the property.  If you instead only want the SID string value to land in your $UserID variable use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID` instead.

Comment: Yes, that works as well ! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work and be faster, with a filterhashtable for get-winevent.  I didn't see userid in the xml named data.

```
$UserID = Get-ADUser Administrator | % sid

Get-WinEvent @{logname = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational'; 
  id = 1102} | ? userid -eq $userid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works as well !